# Facing this issue when I try to run app on my mobile device

Tags: react-native

[C:\Users\Riaz\AwesomeProject>npx react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 896 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
> 15 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 13 up-to-date
> Note: C:\Users\Riaz\AwesomeProject\android\app\src\debug\java\com\awesomeproject\ReactNativeFlipper.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.gradle.internal.compiler.java.ClassNameCollector (in unnamed module @0x1741397c) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$TypeSymbol (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.code to unnamed module @0x1741397c

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 19s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Note: C:\Users\Riaz\AwesomeProject\android\app\src\debug\java\com\awesomeproject\ReactNativeFlipper.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.gradle.internal.compiler.java.ClassNameCollector (in unnamed module @0x1741397c) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$TypeSymbol (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.code to unnamed module @0x1741397c

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 19s

```
at makeError (C:\Users\Riaz\AwesomeProject\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at C:\Users\Riaz\AwesomeProject\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\Riaz\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:5)
at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\Riaz\AwesomeProject\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:186:9)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPi04.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
"script":{
  "start": "react-native run-android"
}
```

with

```
"script":{
    "start": "npx jetify && cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd .. && react-native run-android"
}
```

in `package.json`

then run
`npm run start`
or
`yarn start`